# My app doesn't read added images

Tags: android

Good morning,
Yesterday I updated my Android Studio software to the latest version. From now, my app keeps stopping when I run the apk built in the software.  I noticed that when I deleted all the images and icons of  the app screen the app worked. So I see that when I use: "android:background: @drawable/... " the app will crash in after running the apk. I don't know what happens, because yesterday the app worked very well also with the images or icons in the screen. Please I ask for help, because my app development is now blocked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this. I would suggest to not keep every image in the drawable folder. Instead, keep them in folders according to their size

ldpi  = 240×320 pixels

mdpi = 320×480 pixels

hdpi = 480×800 pixels

xhdpi = 720×1280 pixels

Refer this [link for details](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/create-different-folders-adding-different-resolution-images.html)

Comment: thank you very much!, very helpful. What about the .xml file ?